# Using Pandas, How to find the percentage of a column reaching the target in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

Using Pandas, I'm having trouble how to figure out the percentage of one column reaching the goal in another column. Goal column list numbers and there is a column for the actual pledges. example below. the actual DF has 6000 rows.

| Goal | Pledged |
| --- | --- |
| 9371 | 232 |
| 700 | 745 |
| 20000 | 137 |

How to code the percentage of those that met their goals using pandas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 2], [10, 2]], columns=['goal', 'fact'])
df['goal_fraction'] = df.fact / df.goal
```

To visually transform it to the percentage:

```
df['percentage'] = (df.goal_fraction * 100).round(0).astype(str) + "%"
```

Comment: So after df['percentage'] = (df.goal_fraction * 100).round(0).astype(str) + "%", should i be able to hit enter and I should get the percentage? I called df['percentage'] and I got 0    1117850.0%
1     958157.0%
Name: percentage, dtype: object

Comment: So after df['percentage'] = (df.goal_fraction * 100).round(0).astype(str) + "%", should i be able to hit enter and I should get the percentage?  I called the following......    kickstart = pd.DataFrame([[6, 67071], [7, 67071]], columns=['goal', 'usd_pledged'])
kickstart['goal_fraction'] = kickstart.usd_pledged / kickstart.goal                                         
      0    1117850.0%
       1     958157.0%
Name: percentage, dtype: object

Comment: If we are talking about the reaching of the goal: the dividend is always less than the divisor. Check that in the previous step you divided the columns in the correct order